# Wrong page numbers in the table of contents of a LaTeX document

Tags: table-of-contents, pdf, page-numbering, thesis

I am writing my thesis in LaTeX. Everything was going fine until I decided to insert some of my publications into the LaTeX thesis document.

The error is in the table of contents, which is showing wrong page numbers just in the chapter where I present my papers as PDF documents, LaTeX is considering the PDFs as if they are only one page (the PDF files are more than 6 pages).

For example, paper X starts at page 20 and it is 6 pages long, the next paper should start at page 27, but in the table of contents, it is shown as 21 !.

I should note that the page numbering throughout the document is correct, the error is just in the table of contents.

This is the code of my main tex document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{ThesisStyle}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\include{formatAndDefs}
\begin{document}
\include{TitlePage}
\dominitoc
\pagenumbering{roman}
\section*{Acknowledgments}
\cleardoublepage
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\include{Chapter1}
\include{chapter2}
\include{Chapter3}
\include{Chapter4}
\appendix
\include{Appendix1}
\bibliographystyle{ThesisStyle}
\bibliography{Thesis}
\printnomenclature
\cleardoublepage
\begin{vcenterpage}
\noindent\rule[2pt]{\textwidth}{0.5pt}
{\large\textbf{Abstract:}}
{\large\textbf{Keywords:}}
\noindent\rule[2pt]{\textwidth}{0.5pt}
\end{vcenterpage}
\end{document}
```

In chapter 3, I added the pdf documents:

```
\chapter{List of Publications}
\label{chap:intro}
\minitoc
\newpage
\section{paper 1 title}
\newpage
\includepdf[pages={-}]{paper1.pdf}
\section{paper 2 title}
\newpage
\includepdf[pages={-}]{paper2.pdf}
... etc
```

Where could the error possibly be? (Note: I am new to LaTeX.)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

You might also want to add to your question how you're including the pdfs etc.

Comment: have you re-run latex, the table of contents information is collected from the _previous_ run, so the first run after a large edit will have incorrect numbers, a second run should resolve it

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: I changed all references to “index” into “table of contents”, which seems to be the correct term.